# c++/cli Checking Network Connectivity

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, tcpclient

so here is the code

```
public: static bool TcpSocketTest ()
    {
        try
        {
            System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient Client = gcnew System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient ("www.google.com", 80);

            Client.Close ();

            return true;
        }
        catch (System::Exception ^ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to check the network connectivity and found this code on the internet and changed it a bit to work with my project but it says

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient ^" to "System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient" exists     Project1   33
```

And I'm pretty much new to this so i don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: By using `gcnew` you're creating a handle to an object on the managed heap, in c++-cli you need to indicate it with "hat" symbol `^`. The object initializtion needs to look next: `TcpClient ^ Client = gcnew TcpClient(...`. And also you need to use `->` operator to invoke methods of such object, like: `Client->Close();`. More of that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 1):

In C++/CLI you need to declare object references with a trailing `^`, analogous to the `*` operator for native pointers. Moreover, methods on references most be invoked with the `->` operator. Try this:

```
public: static bool TcpSocketTest ()
    {
        try
        {
            System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient^ Client = gcnew System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient ("www.google.com", 80);

            Client->Close ();

            return true;
        }
        catch (System::Exception ^ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** As Hans Passant points out correctly, there's still another problem with this code, which is not syntactical. Since `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable`, and the `Close()` call is located in the `try` block, the object reference is never disposed of in case of an exception. So the `Close()` call should be outside the `try` block.

However, C++/CLI offers a much better way for dealing with this problem, which is called "stack semantics". It's equivalent  to the C# `using`statement. It's used like that:

```
public: static bool TcpSocketTest ()
    {
        try
        {
            System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient Client (L"www.google.com", 80);

            // Dispose() or Close() not needed anymore

            return true;
        }
        catch (System::Exception ^ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So the `TcpClient` reference is declared like a local variable. But actually, it will be created on the heap, and as soon as the variable `Client` goes out of scope, `Client.Dispose ()` will be called automatically. Hence the `Close()` call is unnecessary altogether, and the object is disposed of properly, no matter if an exception is thrown or the method terminates normally.

Thanks to Hans Passant for pointing this out. Stack semantics for `IDispose` are good practice in C++/CLI.

Note that I changed the String literal in the constructor to `L"..."`. This is good practice, too, because omitting the "L" will result in problems as soon as Unicode characters outside the 8-bit range are used.

Comment: That only stops the compiler from complaining, it is not the correct way to do it.  Google "C++/CLI stack semantics" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant You're right, `IDispose` isn't handled properly here. I addressed just the syntax error in my reply. I've updated my posting correspondingly. Thanks!